# In salt what causes the WARNING 'version' argument will be ignored for multiple package targets

Tags: salt

For some of my `pkg.installed` states I get this warning

> [INFO    ] Executing state pkg.installed for [install haproxy package]
>
> [WARNING ] 'version' argument will be ignored for multiple package targets

I am not specifying a `'version'` argument though.

My state looks like this:

```
"install haproxy package":
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - haproxy
```

Why am I getting this warning and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in salt version 3006.1. See bug report https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/64563.